# Как перемещаться и удалять пробелы по 1, а не по 4?

Tags: atom, tab

В настройках сделал так, чтобы вместо табуляции выставлялось нное количество пробелов.
Но, по пробелам, которые стоят от начала строки до первого символа в строке, редактор перемещается как по табам, то есть через 4 пробела прыгает. Удаляет тоже сразу по 4 пробела. Это жутко не удобно.
Пробелы, которые идут уже после каких-либо символов строке, "работают" нормально.

[image: Скриншот]
Как мне перемещаться и удалять по 1 пробелу?

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Ответили тут: https://toster.ru/q/493840

Решение очень простое - в начале настроек снять галочку с пункта "Atomic Soft Tabs"